# Have a seperate thread push a request to the main thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to have a thread running in the background but pushes a request to the main thread for input before running again. Ideally if a condition is not met when running the thread, than It should request for input before resuming on the 2nd thread.

```
from threading import Thread

def myfun(numofcycles = None):
    if numofcycles is None:
       myrange = range(0,input('Enter number of cycles: '))
    else:
       myrange = range(0,numofcycles)

    for x in myrange:
         print(x)
t = Thread(target=myfun, args = (numofcycles)) # Start the thread
t.start()
```

Comment: I'm thinking you might need a `queue.Queue()` to synchronize and pass data between the threads (?) https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue

Comment: thanks, let me have a look. This might be what I need

Comment: Just posted an example using a queue to pass messages/requests between two threads @HojoTimberwolf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**threading**

The `queue.Queue` object is great for synchronizing between threads and passing data between them. Below I have thread-1 waiting for a command to execute sent from thread-2. You can pass any sort of data between threads over the queue. As you can see, I pass a function and its args to thread-1 over a queue.

```
>>> import queue
>>> import threading as th
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> def thread_func_1(q, n_cycles=2):
...     for _ in range(n_cycles):
...         print("waiting for request from thread 2")
...         try:
...             task, args, kwargs = q.get(timeout=4)
...             print("got request. executing...")
...             task(*args, **kwargs)
...         except queue.Empty:
...             print("timed out waiting for a request")
...             
>>> def thread_func_2(q, n_cycles=2):
...     for _ in range(n_cycles):
...         time.sleep(1)
...         print("sending request to thread 1")
...         q.put((print, ('hello world',), {},))
...         
>>> q    = queue.Queue()
>>>
>>> th_1 = th.Thread(target=thread_func_1, args=(q, 2,))
>>> th_2 = th.Thread(target=thread_func_2, args=(q, 2,))
>>> 
>>> th_1.start(); th_2.start()

waiting for request from thread 2
got request. executing...
hello world
waiting for request from thread 2
got request. executing...
hello world
sending request to thread 1
sending request to thread 1
```

Interesting how putting a comma within a tuple after the last item makes a difference. Doing that fixed the text from thread-2 - it was `h e l l o   w o r l d` before.

Now to have other threads capable of requesting that the main thread execute tasks on their behalf, it would be similar since the main thread is just another thread.

**Main thread task handler**

You could have a task handler loop running in the main thread that performs other tasks - so the app doesn't bog down.. then checks a common `queue.Queue` for requests. When it sees one, it can grab it and execute it and send the result back to the requestor.

You may need more than one queue to support sending back the result of requests to their senders. To implement that, we have the other threads keeping their own `Queue`'s and passing them to the main thread in the request so the main thread can send the result back over it.

```
>>> def main_loop(q, n_cycles=2):
...     for _ in range(n_cycles):
...         try:
...             #task, args, kwargs, client_queue = q.get(block=False)
...             task, args, kwargs, client_queue = q.get(timeout=4)
...
...             print(f"Executing {task.__name__}() for other thread...")
...
...             result = task(*args, **kwargs)
...             client_queue.put(result)
...
...         except queue.Empty:
...             print("Queue was empty, nothing to do...")
...
...             time.sleep(0) # So app doesn't bog down, relinquish control
...                           # when idle to let other threads have more time.
```

This gives a rough idea for a task queue loop running on the main thread. you wouldn't want to block reading the queue (I just have a timeout for the example).

Plus a good tip is, always put a `time.sleep(0)` in the loop when the main thread is idle. This makes the app remain responsive and gives the other threads more time to do their work. Without that sleep, the app can get sluggish since the main thread is selfishly spinning away wasting processor cycles on nothing most of the time.

**Something to consider - multiprocessing**

If the application really needs to leverage the full processing power of the CPU by running concurrent threads, Python's `threading` module doesn't support this. Only one thread can be actively running Python code at a time (per interpreter).

To have workers running truly concurrent, the `multiprocessing` module is the way to go. It supports a similar API to the `multithreading` module, but utilizes processes instead of threads.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for